# query: return all rows even if the count of the associated rows are 0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have this query:

```
$oe = OE::select([
    'oe.id',
    'oe.id_cartao', 
    'oe.nome', 
    'oe.email',
    \DB::raw('count(trienios.oe_id) as count')
])->leftjoin('trienios', 'trienios.oe_id', '=', 'oe.id')
->groupBy('trienios.oe_id');
```

which translates to the following query:

```
select `oe`.`id`, `oe`.`id_cartao`, `oe`.`nome`, `oe`.`email`, count(trienios.oe_id) as count 

from `oe` 

left join `trienios` on `trienios`.`oe_id` = `oe`.`id` 

group by `trienios`.`oe_id
```

However, if there are no results in the `trienios` table, the query will only return a single record from the `oe` table. I want to return all the results from the `oe` table even if there are no results in the `trienios` table. How do I do that?

Comment: groupby apply on primary  table not join table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set group by on primary table

```
select `oe`.`id`, `oe`.`id_cartao`, `oe`.`nome`, `oe`.`email`, count(trienios.oe_id) as count from `oe` left join `trienios` on `trienios`.`oe_id` = `oe`.`id` group by `oe`.`id`
```

Comment: here i post simple query solution